# Query to get total count of States when values are stored as both abbreviation and full name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a query to return the total count of states for participants in our database. This should be straightforward enough normally; however the data that we migrated from a client originally stored the states as the abbreviated 2-letter acronym, but since taking over, we have standardized displaying the full name of the state. I tried using a CASE WHEN statement; however I don't want to have to hardcode every state/territory that we have stored in our system for my query unless that is the only way to accomplish this task. My query is posted below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE NVARCHAR(100), STATE_ABBREVIATION NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('AB', 'AB')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('AE', 'AE')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Alabama', 'AL')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Alaska', 'AK')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('AP', 'AP')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Arkansas', 'AR')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Arizona', 'AZ')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Armed Forces Pacific', 'Armed Forces Pacific')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('BC', 'BC')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('California', 'CA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Colorado', 'CO')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Connecticut', 'CT')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Delaware', 'DE')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('District of Columbia', 'DC')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Florida', 'FL')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('FM', 'FM')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Georgia', 'GA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Hawaii', 'HI')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Idaho', 'ID')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Illinois', 'IL')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Indiana', 'IN')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Iowa', 'IA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Kansas', 'KS')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Kentucky', 'KY')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Louisiana', 'LA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Maine', 'ME')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Maryland', 'MD')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Massachusetts', 'MS')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Michigan', 'MI')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Minnesota', 'MN')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Mississippi', 'MS')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Missouri', 'MO')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Montana', 'MT')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('N/A', 'N/A')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Nebraska', 'NE')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Nevada', 'NV')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('New Hampshire', 'NH')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('New Jersey', 'NJ')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('New Mexico', 'NM')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('New York', 'NY')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('North Carolina', 'NC')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('North Dakota', 'ND')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Ohio', 'OH')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Oklahoma', 'OK')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('ON', 'ON')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Oregon', 'OR')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Pennsylvania', 'PA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Puerto Rico', 'Puerto Rico')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Rhode Island', 'RI')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('South Dakota', 'SD')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('South Carolina', 'SC')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Tennessee', 'TN')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Texas', 'TX')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Utah', 'UT')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Vermont', 'VT')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Virginia', 'VA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Washington', 'WA')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('West Virginia', 'WV')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Wisconsin', 'WI')
INSERT INTO #tempstates (STATE_PROVINCE, STATE_ABBREVIATION) VALUES ('Wyoming', 'WY')

SELECT       ts.STATE_PROVINCE
            ,count(dd.STATE_PROVINCE) as 'State_Count'
FROM DEMOGRAPHIC_DATA dd
JOIN #tempstates ts on dd.STATE_PROVINCE in (ts.STATE_ABBREVIATION, ts.STATE_PROVINCE)
GROUP BY ts.STATE_PROVINCE, dd.STATE_PROVINCE
ORDER BY dd.STATE_PROVINCE, State_Count

DROP TABLE #tempstates
```

I would like the query to return only the count of the states that have the full name value displayed; however include the count of their abbreviated version counterpart as well.

EDITED:
The below image depicts an example of the issue that I have, Arizona and AZ each have their own respective counts, whereas I would like the end result to yield "Arizona | 47". I have updated my query to include a temp table where I join the source table to it. I am still running into problems as the output results either the abbreviated state name or the full state name count and not the total combined if an abbreviation and full name pair exist.
[image]

Comment: What is your question here, exactly? if you want both the name *and* abbreviation, then include both of those columns in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: "I don't want to have to hardcode every state/territory that we have stored in our system for my query" -- then don't, that's what tables are for. Make a mapping table or extend an existing one with a column to hold the abbreviation, then join.

Comment: There are some strange things in your query: if `STATE_PROVINCE` is not nullable then `COUNT(STATE_PROVINCE)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`. Also no point doing `order by STATE_PROVINCE, State_Count` as `STATE_PROVINCE` will be unique anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping table that will map 2-letter acronyms to the values you want to use, then JOIN that table in your query or use it to update values.

```
CREATE TABLE StateMap (
    Acronym VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FullName VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT StateMap (Acronym, FullName)
VALUES ('AK', 'Alaska'),
       ('MI', 'Michigan'),
       ('NY', 'New York')
       ....;

SELECT FullName,
       ,count(FullName) as 'State_Count'
FROM DEMOGRAPHIC_DATA dem
INNER JOIN StateMap sm on sm.Acronym = dem.STATE_PROVINCE;
```

Comment: You need to join using both Acronym and FullName since the source table can contain either. Effectively `INNER JOIN StateMap sm on dem.STATE_PROVINCE in (sm.Acronym, sm.FullName)`  [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13d38270cf6ecb754519208b4c7c78e8)

Comment: Yes, if the source table actually includes both.  It's not clear that it does.